# OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

Tags: git, vmware, shared-directory, repo

Ubuntu 16.04.4 is running on windows 7 VM. I am trying to repo init into a shared folder. That shared folder is shared with a Windows VM, and the filesystem of that share does not support symlinks. I am getting below error OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported.

```
buildbrain@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean$ repo init -u ssh://git- 
master:29418/testing -b master -m manifest.xml
Get git://git-mirror-builders:9418/testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
_Main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 399, in 
Execute
self._SyncManifest(opt)
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 171, in 
_SyncManifest
m._InitGitDir(mirror_git=mirrored_manifest_git)
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2292, in 
_InitGitDir
self._UpdateHooks()
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2312, in 
_UpdateHooks
self._InitHooks()
File "/mnt/hgfs/dvs/git/clean/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2341, in 
_InitHooks
os.symlink(os.path.relpath(stock_hook, os.path.dirname(dst)), dst)
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

I tried some of the solutions from the net but still not able to solve this issue. Anybody help me here with this issue.

Some helpful links you can take a look - https://github.com/mlsecproject/combine/issues/173

Comment: Don't do any work in shared folders if at all possible. Since you're using Git, it is possible to avoid working in shared folders.

Comment: I need to repo init in the shared location, any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't know what's making you need to do it, but whatever it is, fix that, because there seems to be no fixing the shared-folder issue.